# PHP GET: Undefined index even though the access log shows it is there

Tags: php, get

Error_log:

> [Fri Jul 28 20:07:46.827740 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 5991] [client 79.146.9.122:48057] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: close in /home/x/public_html/mt4/index.php on line 3

Access_log:

> 79.146.9.122 - - [28/Jul/2017:20:07:46 +0200] "POST /mt4/index.php?close=0.06949000 HTTP/1.1" 200 3 "-" "MetaTrader 4 Terminal/4.1090 (Windows NT 5.1; x64)"

Code:

```
<?php
$f=fopen('eth-btc.json','w');
fwrite($f,$_POST['close']);
fclose($f);
echo 200;
?>
```

Also tried with `$_GET['close']` and `$_REQUEST['close']`

Comment: `if(!empty($_GET['close'])){ $f=fopen ... echo 200; }` if you're at liberty to modify that code, or `isset()`.

Comment: However, you have both POST and a GET array, that would trigger it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your access log it should be `$_POST`

```
  fwrite($f,$_POST['close']);
```

Comment: same issue with that

Answer (score 1):

use $_REQUEST['close'] instead of $_GET['close']

Comment: same issue with that

Comment: may I ask you new logs...